# Hive insert overwrite directory stored as parquet made NULL values

Tags: hive

I'm trying to add some data in one directory, and after to add these data as partition to a table.

```
create table test (key int, value int) partitioned by (dt int) stored as parquet location '/user/me/test';
insert overwrite directory '/user/me/test/dt=1' stored as parquet select 123, 456, 1;
alter table test add partition (dt=1);
select * from test;
```

This code sample is simple... but don't work. With the select statement, the output is NULL, NULL, 1. But I need 123, 456, 1.

When I read the data with Impala, I received 123, 456, 1... what is expected.

Why ? What is wrong ?

If I removed the two "stored as parquet", it's all ok... but I want my data in parquet !

PS : I want this construct for a switch of partition, so that when the data are calculated, they don't go to the user...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Identifying the issue

**hive**

```
create table test (key int, value int)
partitioned by (dt int) 
stored as parquet location '/user/me/test'
;

insert overwrite directory '/user/me/test/dt=1' 
stored as parquet 
select 123, 456
;

alter table test add partition (dt=1)
;

select * from test
;

+----------+------------+---------+
| test.key | test.value | test.dt |
+----------+------------+---------+
| NULL     | NULL       |       1 |
+----------+------------+---------+
```

**bash**

```
parquet-tools cat hdfs://{fs.defaultFS}/user/me/test/dt=1/000000_0
```

---

```
_col0 = 123
_col1 = 456
```

#### Verifying the issue

**hive**

```
alter table test change column `key`    `_col0` int cascade;
alter table test change column `value`  `_col1` int cascade;

select * from test
;    

+------------+------------+---------+
| test._col0 | test._col1 | test.dt |
+------------+------------+---------+
|        123 |        456 |       1 |
+------------+------------+---------+
```

## Suggestd Solution

create additional table `test_admin` and do the insert through it

```
create table test_admin (key int, value int) 
partitioned by (dt int) 
stored as parquet location '/user/me/test'
;

create external table test (key int, value int) 
partitioned by (dt int) 
stored as parquet 
location '/user/me/test'
;

insert into test_admin partition (dt=1) select 123, 456
;

select * from test_admin
;

+----------+------------+---------+
| test.key | test.value | test.dt |
+----------+------------+---------+
|      123 |        456 |       1 |
+----------+------------+---------+

select * from test
;

(empty result set)

alter table test add partition (dt=1)
;

select * from test
;

+----------+------------+---------+
| test.key | test.value | test.dt |
+----------+------------+---------+
|      123 |        456 |       1 |
+----------+------------+---------+
```

Comment: is there any way I can write directly into directory without creating table?